# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException "Graph"

Tags: java, exception

I am a beginner in Java and I get this  `java.util.InputMismatchException` for the code I have written it below. The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at Graph.main(Graph.java:103)
```

Once debugging it gives the error when it is going to execute `int size = scan.nextInt();` line in main methor. I would appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

```
    import java.io.*;
    enter code here`import java.util.*;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class Graph {
       private int maxSize;
       private Vertex[] nodes; // array of nodes
       private int[][] mat; // adjacency matrix
       private int N;
       public Graph(int maxSize) {
          this.maxSize = maxSize;
          nodes = new Vertex[maxSize];
          mat = new int[maxSize][maxSize];
          for(int i=0; i<maxSize;i++)
             for(int j=0; j<maxSize;j++) mat[i][j]=0;
       }
       public void addVertex(int x, int y) {
          if (N >= maxSize) {
             System.out.println("Graph full");
             return;}
          nodes[N++] = new Vertex(x , y);
       }
       public void addEdge(int v1, int v2) {
          mat[v1][v2] = 1;
          mat[v2][v1] = 1;
       }
       //public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
       public void readFile() throws IOException

       {  
                int xcoord;
          int ycoord;
          Scanner scan = new Scanner("vertex.txt");
          int size = scan.nextInt();
          int count = 0;
          while (scan.hasNext() && count<size) {
                     scan.nextLine();

             nodes[count].setX(scan.nextInt());
             nodes[count].setY(scan.nextInt());

             count++;         

          }
          //Reads the edges file
          Scanner scanEdge = new Scanner("edges.txt");
          size = scanEdge.nextInt();


          count = 0;
          int weight;
    //fill out the adjacency matrix
          while (scanEdge.hasNext() && count<size) {
             scanEdge.nextLine();
             xcoord = scanEdge.nextInt(); // "from" node
             ycoord = scanEdge.nextInt(); // "to" node
             mat[xcoord][ycoord]=scanEdge.nextInt(); //weigth of the link
             mat[ycoord][xcoord] = mat[xcoord][ycoord]; //Symmetric matrix
             count++;         
             scanEdge.nextLine();

          }

          return;
       }  



       public static void main(String args[]){

          EasyIn easy = new EasyIn();
        // Prints menu
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println("Welcome to Maze Genrator App");
          System.out.println("=============================");
          System.out.println("Menu");
          System.out.println("====");
          System.out.println("1- Read Graph from File");
          System.out.println("2- Generate a Graph using a Grid with Random weigths");
          System.out.println("3- Compute the Minimum Spanning Tree");
          System.out.println("0- Exit");

          int command = -1;
          while (command != 0) {
             if (command > 0) {String pause = easy.readString();} //Creates a pause
             System.out.println();
             command = easy.readInt(); //Takes command
             switch (command){
                case 1:
               //Reads the vertices file. 

                   Scanner scan = new Scanner("vertex.txt");

                   int size = scan.nextInt();
                //Reads the vertices file

                   Graph myGraph = new Graph(size);

                //String fileName = easy.readString();
                   try{
                      myGraph.readFile();            
                   }
                   catch(IOException e){
                      e.printStackTrace();
                   }

                   System.out.println("List of edges + weigths");

                   break;

                case 0: //Exit command
                   break;
                default:
                   System.out.println("Selection Invalid!- Try Again");
             }
          }

          System.out.println("Goodbye!");
       }
    }

    public class Vertex {
    // The vertex coordinates
    private int x;//label e.g. A,B
    private int y;//label e.g. A,B
    public boolean visited;     //Wether the node is visited or not
    public Vertex (int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    visited = false;
    }
    //display x,y coordinates of the graph
    public void display() {
    System.out.println(x + "  " + y);
    }
    //set x coordinate
    public void setX(int x){
    this.x = x;

    }
    //set y coordinate
    public void setY(int y){
    this.y = y;

    }

    }
```

Comment: Does `vertex.txt` contain anything which is not a number? Like a header row, commas etc?

Comment: it only contains integers. Here is the content of vertext file
9
0 0
1 0
2 0
0 1
1 1
2 1
0 2
1 2
2 2

Answer (score 1):

> Once debugging it gives the error when it is going to execute "int
> size = scan.nextInt();" line

It means that the next token isn't an integer.

You may want to call and check the return value of `scan.hasNextInt()`, to prevent this Exception.

Documentation says :

> public class InputMismatchException extends NoSuchElementException
>
> Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not
> match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of
> range for the expected type.

Comment: Actually the file that I am reading from only contains integers though.

Comment: So, use hasNextInt() to be sure . Documentation for InputMismatchException in nextInt(), is pretty clear about what it means.

Comment: Thank you! I took the return value for scan.hasNextInt(); it gave me false!! But actually the file that I am reading from only contains integers! I am confused.

Comment: Maybe there is a space character or so ? Have a look at what is written at the file position where hasNextInt() says "false". You may call next() to check it out.

Answer (score -2):

```
new Scanner("vertex.txt")
```

This is a Scanner which reads the passed String (and not a file with that name). Since this String contains a filename and not a number it will fail.

What you're looking for is:

```
new Scanner(new File("vertex.txt"))
```

This one will first create a 'File' instance with the given filename and then pass that to the Scanner, so it will actually read the content of this file.

The same applies to your Scanner for the *"edges.txt"*.